# Is it possible to set the outerHTML for a HTMLDocument?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, dom, outerhtml

Below is the code i use to alter the HTML displayed in IE. However it always throws exception - Could not set the outerHTML property. Invalid target element for this operation. Ain't it possible to set the outerHTML?

```
protected void AlterContent(ref HTMLDocument docInput, HTMLDocument docAlteredOutPut)
{
    try
    {
        if (docInput.body.tagName.ToLower() == "body" && docAlteredOutPut.body.innerHTML != null)
        {
            docInput.documentElement.outerHTML = docAlteredOutPut.documentElement.outerHTML;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you're talking about WebBrowser control? Or something else?

Comment: Yes, I was talking of WebBrowser control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot replace the html for the`<body>`element.  There's no need to, this works fine:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com");
        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }
    void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
        var body = webBrowser1.Document.Body;
        body.InnerHtml = "pwned";
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand what you have done. But I need to replace the entire html not just the body. That is why tried accessing OuterHTML

Comment: Just generate the document directly, it is pointless to retrieve it from the server and then not use it.  Assign the WebBrowser.DocumentText property.

Comment: I get that. But again thats not what i need to do. I took the html source of a page in IE and changed it.
I took it using this - 

WebBrowser Explorer;
HTMLDocument docInput = (HTMLDocument)Explorer.Document;

Now after I make the required changes to docInput, I made alterations inside the <head> tag also, I want to replace the actual document with this one. Is there some way to do it all in one go?

Comment: @arunondeck did u manage to sort this out? I'm having the exact same problem!

Comment: @Ricky: The outerHTML property cannot be set. I had to write something else to avoid reaching this phase.